# Google Drive API - sharing 'appDataFolder'

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Is it possible to share folders that are inside Google drive ['Application Data'](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata) directory?

I've saw quite a few similar questions on SO, but none with the answer.

Comment: I seriously doubt it.   However i think i will ping someone to check

Comment: just tried to get permissions of file under Application Data directory using 
Google Drive REST API and got status code 403 with message "Method not supported for files within the Application Data folder."

Comment: Guess we have our answer then.   I am still waiting for a response from someone on the team.   I would post your comment as an answer and accept it in the mean time.

Comment: I also have the same problem and still did not get a clear answer. But according the error "Method not supported for files within the Application Data folder." it is not possible.